# How do I pass in multiple property keys as arguments to a function which uses bracket notation?

Tags: javascript

The following code tries to count the occurrences of `value` that fall under the passed `key` tree in `myArr`. It works if the `key` is only passed as one property, trying to pass in two doesn't work. Is there a simple syntax fix?

EDIT: I'm trying to do this with a simple for loop solution

```js
let myArr = [
  {
    'level 1': {
      'level 2': 'val'
    }
  }
]

Array.prototype.count = function (key, value) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
    if (this[i][key] == value) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count
}

var theCount = myArr.count(['level 1']['level 2'], 'val')
console.log(theCount)
```

Comment: I've rolled back some of your edits. Please refrain from updating your question with code taken from answers to your question. If an answer is sufficient for your original question but you'd like to take a different approach, you can specify that (which you have), but don't create a moving target, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `count` an array of keys and a value:

```js
const myArr = [{
  'level 1': {
    'level 2': 'val'
  }
}, {
  'prop 1': {
    'prop 2': 'val 2'
  }
}, {
  'prop 1': {
    'prop 2': 'val 2'
  }
}];

// lazy solution, if you need to possibly find a value of `false`,
// will have to write more elaborate code:
const keysToInnerVal = (inputObj, keys) => keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
  if (!obj) return false;
  return obj[key];
}, inputObj);
Array.prototype.count = function(keys, findValue) {
  return this.reduce((matchCountSoFar, item) => (
    matchCountSoFar + (keysToInnerVal(item, keys) === findValue)
  ), 0);
}

console.log(myArr.count(['level 1', 'level 2'], 'val'));
console.log(myArr.count(['prop 1', 'prop 2'], 'val 2'));
```

Same thing with a `for` loop instead of the `keysToInnerVal` function's `reduce`:

```js
const myArr = [{
  'level 1': {
    'level 2': 'val'
  }
}, {
  'prop 1': {
    'prop 2': 'val 2'
  }
}, {
  'prop 1': {
    'prop 2': 'val 2'
  }
}];

const keysToInnerVal = (inputObj, keys) => keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
  if (!obj) return false;
  return obj[key];
}, inputObj);
Array.prototype.count = function(keys, findValue) {
  return this.reduce((matchCountSoFar, item) => {
    let ref = item;
    for (const key of keys) {
      if (ref === undefined) return matchCountSoFar;
      ref = ref[key];
    }
    return matchCountSoFar + (ref === findValue);
  }, 0);
}

console.log(myArr.count(['level 1', 'level 2'], 'val'));
console.log(myArr.count(['prop 1', 'prop 2'], 'val 2'));
```

Without any `reduce` at all:

```js
const myArr = [{
  'level 1': {
    'level 2': 'val'
  }
}, {
  'prop 1': {
    'prop 2': 'val 2'
  }
}, {
  'prop 1': {
    'prop 2': 'val 2'
  }
}];

const keysToInnerVal = (inputObj, keys) => keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
  if (!obj) return false;
  return obj[key];
}, inputObj);
Array.prototype.count = function(keys, findValue) {
  let matchCount = 0;
  outer:
  for (const item of this) {
    let ref = item;
    for (const key of keys) {
      if (ref === undefined) continue outer;
      ref = ref[key];
    }
    matchCount += (ref === findValue);
  }
  return matchCount;
}

console.log(myArr.count(['level 1', 'level 2'], 'val'));
console.log(myArr.count(['prop 1', 'prop 2'], 'val 2'));
```

As said in comment, mutating built-in objects like `Array` is *terrible* practice - bad libraries doing that sort of thing is what put the `flatten` [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-flatMap/pull/56) on hold for a while. Try to avoid it if at all possible - for example, you could have a standalone `count` function that gets passed the array, the keys, and the value to find.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for any array length without using reduce?
https://jsfiddle.net/ocea7t86/2/

Comment: Sure, if you want you can use a `for` loop and iterate over all keys, I like `reduce` because it's clear and functional.

Comment: The syntax still eludes me for passing the array to the bracket notation: https://jsfiddle.net/ocea7t86/16/

Comment: See edit, I removed the `keysToInnerVal` with its `reduce` and used a `for` loop instead

Comment: It's still using reduce though in Array.protoype.count,
What I'm really trying to learn is how do I turn an array of items into bracket notation, without using reduce or anything else, just a for loop building a bracket notation based on the length of the array.

For example:
`myArr` of length 1 would be `myArr[1]`.
`myArr` of length 2 would be `myArr[1]myArr[2]`.
Then I can use it like `this[i][myArr[1]]` or `this[i][myArr[1]][myArr[2]]`